# document_library in Liferay

Tags: properties, liferay, filepath

I have this line in my portal-ext.properties:

```
# Document library location
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=/data/document_library
```

But when I try to upload some picture or another file nothing happened in my `document_library` folder. I have `folderId=0` and `treePath=/0/` in my `dlfileentry` table. What's the problem?

Comment: What Liferay version? What is the value of `dl.store.impl`? How do you upload files? Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: You need to have complete folder path for property `dl.store.file.system.root.dir` ; /data/document_library does not seems complete path.

Comment: On any *nix system `/data/document_library` is a valid absolute path. If your intention was to have that in `data` folder under Liferay's home folder you should have `${liferay.home}/data/document_library` instead (which is the default)!

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya, thank you, it helps. Write your comment as answer, I'll vote it up and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have complete folder path for property `dl.store.file.system.root.dir` ; /data/document_library does not seems complete path